# How to set Yii2 ActiveDataProvider's page dynamically with jquery

Tags: jquery, gridview, pagination, yii2

I'm building an web-based application using Yii2. I used Yii2's GridView and I would like to use dropdown for the pagination instead of bootstrap's default pagination which used series of button. My GridView is wrapped with a Pjax. This is my current code:

```
<div class="custom-pagination">
    Page <?=Html::dropDownList('myPagination', '1', $pageOptions);?> Of <?=$pageCount;?>
</div>

//********
my gridview which is wrapped by pjax
//********

<script type="text/javascript">
var base = "<?=Yii::$app->request->getAbsoluteUrl();?>";
$(".custom-pagination select").on('change', function(e){
    $.get( base, {'page': $(this).val()}, function( data ) {
        $.pjax.reload({container:'#kv-grid-demo-pjax', url: base});
    });
});
</script>
```

On server side:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new RotaryInputSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $pageCount = ceil($dataProvider->getTotalCount() / $dataProvider->getPagination()->getPageSize());
    $pageOptions = array();
    for($i=1; $i<=$pageCount; $i++) {
        $pageOptions[$i] = $i;
    }

    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $dataProvider->pagination->page = $_GET['page'];
        echo json_encode('success');
        die();
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'pageCount' => $pageCount,
        'pageOptions' => $pageOptions,
    ]);
}
```

The pjax's working and the grid is reloaded, but it won't turn to other page and stays on page 1. I have no idea what I should do with this. Please help...

Comment: can you pls give little bit more html and js this is not enough for understanding your issue

Comment: This is all I have in my controller, js and view. What other part would you like to know?

Comment: what is the value of variable `base' in your jquery get method

Comment: edited the code.
base is the current absolute URL of the app.

Comment: can you pls try this `$(".custom-pagination select").on('change', function(e){
   $.pjax.reload({container:'#kv-grid-demo-pjax', url: base+'?page='+$(this).val()});
});`

Comment: It works great. Thanks Samuel, I've never thought about url: base+'?page='+$(this).val() before, but unfortunately, this removes the grid's filter completely.

Comment: pls load to a div inside the grid filter

Answer (score 0):

Following code will works fine for you

```
$(".custom-pagination select").on('change', function(e){
   $.pjax.reload({container:'#kv-grid-demo-pjax', url: base+'?page='+$(this).val()});
});
```

Comment: Sorry the comment is too long so I shall put more comment here. It works great, but unfortunately, this removes the grid's filter completely. What do you mean by "load to a div inside the grid filter"?